# get sum rows based on column values

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have the data like this

[image]

I want below result.

[image]

Comment: Why do you have two fields with the same name, `Quantity`?...such a thing is generally not possible except for in an adhoc query. What is your table definitions for this dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Select [Commodity], [Business Entities], [Quantity]
from MyTable

UNION ALL

SELECT [Commodity], 'TOTAL', SUM([Quantity])
from MyTable
group by [Commodity]
order by [Commodity]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUPING SETS` for this

```sql
SELECT
  Commodity,
  [Business Entities] = CASE WHEN GROUPING([Business Entities]) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE [Business Entities] END,
  Quantity = SUM(Quantity)
FROM YourTabe
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
    (Commodity, [Business Entities]),
    (Commodity)
)
ORDER BY
  [Commodity],
  GROUPING([Business Entities]),
  [Business Entities];
```

The `GROUPING` function tells us if a column has been grouped or not.